# Registering database to ArcGIS for Server?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server

I want to register an SDE geodatabase to ArcGIS for server 10.1 . I use SQl server 2008 R2 , 
ArcGIS 10.1 . I backup my database from server "a" and restor to server "B" then I used registering database in ArcGIS publisher .I successfully registered database (fig1), but when 
i want to publish my map ,the warning raised **" datasource is not registerd with the server and data will be copied to the server"**(fig2) . How do i get rid of the warning ?

[image: fig1]

[image: fig2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like you are encountering a warning that is documented as [24011: Data source is not registered with the server and data will be copied to the server](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00sq000000m5000000).

The two solutions offered are:

> - Do nothing. The source data will be copied to the ArcGIS server. ...
> - If you do not wish to copy your data to the server you will need to register the original data source with the ArcGIS server.

but I recommend that you read all the information on that help page.

Comment: Thanks , Making your data accessible to ArcGIS Server solve my problem